# How do I disable or hide the pink background on missing fonts

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How do I disable or hide the pink background on missing fonts? I do not care that the fonts are missing. I do not want to install the fonts. I do not want to replace the fonts in the file; I want to keep the fonts the same even though I have opened the file on a computer that does not have these fonts installed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Understand that you **can not** *"Keep the fonts the same"* unless you install the fonts on your system. The pink background is telling you that the fonts **are not** displaying correctly.

In any event, you can turn off the pink background by navigating to `Preferences > Type` and *unchecking* the `Enable Missing Glyph Protection` option or, if using Illustrator CC, the `Highlight Substituted Fonts` option.

Comment: I left Enable Missing Glyph Protection checked and unchecked "Highlight Substituted Fonts" and that did what I wanted. Thanks

Comment: By "Keep the fonts the same" I mean that when I save the file and open it on a computer with the fonts installed, I don't want any of the fonts to have changed.

Comment: "Highlight Substituted font" is an Illustrator CC option. It's not in CS6. I was looking at CS6 at the time :)

Answer (score 2):

Try: Preferences > Type and make sure'Highlight Substituted Fonts' is unchecked